# Android (Things) DHCP Server

Tags: android, dhcp, android-things

I am working on a project using Android Things (Dev Preview 2).

The project requires that up to 10 nodes be assigned IP addresses from a DHCP server. I have used isc-dhcp-server in the past with Linux, but cannot find any documentation on how to accomplish this in Android (any variant).

Any tips or links to documentation would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Android Things will request an IP from a local DHCP server automatically by default (as well as other versions of Android) which software runs the DHCP server is quite irrelevant.

Or maybe your question is about running a DHCP server in Android?